# Implementing Method with Generics

Tags: java, android, generics

I have some code I want generalize.

I have a generic class

```
public class SynthesisFragmentAdapter<A extends Fragment & IBaseFragment, B extends Fragment & IBaseFragment> extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context context;

    private Class<A> synthesisFragmentClass1;

    private Class<B> synthesisFragmentClass2;

    public SynthesisFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, 
                                          Class<A> synthesisFragmentClass1, 
                                          Class<B> synthesisFragmentClass2) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        this.synthesisFragmentClass1 = synthesisFragmentClass1;
        this.synthesisFragmentClass2= synthesisFragmentClass2;
    }

}
```

I want call this class when i need to add a fragment dynamically to the `SynthesisFragmentAdapter` instance. I tried this

```
// dynamically add same kind of fragment to adapter
    protected void init(Class a, Class b , Fragment f1 , Fragment f2) {

            TabLayout tab = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);

            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

            SynthesisFragmentAdapter<f1 , f2> fragmentAdapter = new SynthesisFragmentAdapter<f1, f2>(getSupportFragmentManager(), this , a , b);
            pager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
            tab.setupWithViewPager(pager);
        }
```

But I don't think this is right because the fragments I am using implement an interface (`IBaseFragment`) in addition to extending `Fragment`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any compile errors or runtime exceptions? Does the program do what you want it to do?

Comment: @Erick G. Hagstrom . Thank you for your reply . Indeed i got a compile error under the instantiation of the SynthesisFragmentAdapter : "unknown class f1 , unknown class f2"). I think i am missing something but i don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See declaration of method `init` and its usage.

Updated code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected <A extends Fragment & IBaseFragment, B extends Fragment & IBaseFragment> void init(Class<A> classA, Class<B> classB) {
    TabLayout tab = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    SynthesisFragmentAdapter<A, B> fragmentAdapter = new SynthesisFragmentAdapter<>(getSupportFragmentManager(), this, classA, classB);
    pager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
    tab.setupWithViewPager(pager);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init(FragmentA.class, FragmentB.class);
}

interface IBaseFragment {
}


public static class FragmentA extends Fragment implements IBaseFragment {
}


public static class FragmentB extends Fragment implements IBaseFragment {

}

public class SynthesisFragmentAdapter<A extends Fragment & IBaseFragment, B extends Fragment & IBaseFragment> extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    private Context context;

    private Class<A> synthesisFragmentClass1;

    private Class<B> synthesisFragmentClass2;

    public SynthesisFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context,
                                    Class<A> synthesisFragmentClass1,
                                    Class<B> synthesisFragmentClass2) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        this.synthesisFragmentClass1 = synthesisFragmentClass1;
        this.synthesisFragmentClass2 = synthesisFragmentClass2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: There ya go! Put the type args on the `init()` method too! Ok, I think you have a winner here.

Comment: @gio It works perfectly . I have never seen such a method declaration . I would never found it without your help oO. I don't know how to thank you . You saved me a lot of troubles man. Thank you very much !

Comment: @ulquiorra: you're welcome, btw you can find more interesting things about all of that at [official java tutorial, Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the system doesn't really know the type of `f1` and `f2` at compile time, which is when it checks the type arguments. Type arguments are erased at run time, so can't be checked based on whatever those method arguments are.

How about changing your declaration of `SynthesisFragmentAdapter`? Do you really need the `extends` notation in the type parameters? Perhaps all you really need is:

```
public class SynthesisFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    // ...
    private Class<? extends Fragment> synthesisFragmentClass1;
    private Class<? extends Fragment> synthesisFragmentClass2;
    // etc.
```

It just doesn't look like you really *need* generics here.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Initially I wanted to do without generics because i have some troubles with them but it was mandatory in my specifications rules :(